# Как правильно реализовать совместный роутинг backend + spa?

Tags: symfony2, маршрутизация, marionette.js, spa

Реализую задачу, где используются Symfony 2.8 и Marionette.js. Необходимо, что бы при обращение на url`ы:

```
'/'
'/album/:id'
'/album/:id/page/:page'
```

после рендеринга html открывался соответсвующий роут у marionette.

В случаи с react пишут изоморфные приложения с рендерингом на серверной части. В данной ситуации не знаю как правильно решается такой вопрос. Не писать же три web роута на выдачу одного и тоже html.

Comment: *Не писать же три web роута на выдачу одного и тоже html.* -- ну, это как минимум **сработает**.

Comment: приложение будет рости, буду роуты добавляться, где-то что-то забудется, не вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, никак. Придётся писать 3 роута, которые будут вести на один и тот же контроллер (с разными параметрами). Но ничего плохого в таком подходе нет, это вполне стандартное решение, и у нас многие приложения работают по такой схеме.

```
homepage:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show }

album_show:
    path:      /album/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show }

album_show__page:
    path:      /album/{id}/page/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show, page: 1 }
```

Похожий (но не совсем) кейс в доке по симфони: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements